Overcome 1000 rows limit in power bi via Succesfuctors API
I am trying to get the data from API SF in the Json format. the data is there and correct, however I can't bring more than 1000 rows. here below you will find the M code query.
Please note that in power query it shows only 1000 rows ( because with other data sets from other sources I can see the exact number of rows but in here it shows only 1000)
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(" https://api55.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/User?$format=JSON", [Headers=[Authorization="Basic QkMwMDBJTlRAYWJkdWxsYWhhYjpTY2llbmNlU29mdDE5ODk="]])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded d" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "d", {"results", "__next"}, {"d.results", "d.__next"}),
    #"Expanded d.results" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded d", "d.results"),
    #"Expanded d.results1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results", "d.results", {"__metadata", "userId", "country", "zipCode", "lastModifiedDateTime", "reviewFreq", "jobCode", "lastModifiedWithTZ", "division", "custom02", "custom01", "custom04", "custom03", "custom06", "custom05", "custom08", "addressLine1", "custom07", "addressLine2", "sciLastModified", "custom09", "onboardingId", "state", "fax", "mi", "timeZone", "defaultLocale", "firstName", "teamMembersSize", "lastReviewDate", "businessPhone", "lastModified", "status", "empId", "lastName", "gender", "impactOfLoss", "city", "benchStrength", "displayName", "department", "isPrimaryAssignment", "email", "assignmentUUID", "hireDate", "companyExitDate", "talentPool", "custom11", "defaultFullName", "custom10", "reasonForLeaving", "riskOfLoss", "custom13", "custom12", "custom15", "custom14", "location", "totalTeamSize", "username", "delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav", "secondManager", "nominationNav", "reasonForLeavingNav", "hr", "incumbentOfPositionNav", "headOfUnitOfFOBusinessUnitNav", "customManager", "costCenterManagerOfFOCostCenterNav", "employmentIdentityOfDRTMPurgeFreezeNav", "matrixManager", "secondReports", "custom02Nav", "proxy", "userIdOfEmployeePayrollRunResultsNav", "matrixReports", "directReports", "externalCodeOfSkillProfileNav", "personKeyNav", "headOfUnitOfFODepartmentNav", "headOfUnitOfFODivisionNav", "hrReports", "riskOfLossNav", "benchStrengthNav", "manager", "assigneeUserIdOfDomainEventAlertNav", "talentPoolNav", "impactOfLossNav", "ownerOfTalentPoolNav", "competencyRatingNav", "customReports", "userPermissionsNav", "delegateeOfAutoDelegateDetailNav"}, {"d.results.__metadata", "d.results.userId", "d.results.country", "d.results.zipCode", "d.results.lastModifiedDateTime", "d.results.reviewFreq", "d.results.jobCode", "d.results.lastModifiedWithTZ", "d.results.division", "d.results.custom02", "d.results.custom01", "d.results.custom04", "d.results.custom03", "d.results.custom06", "d.results.custom05", "d.results.custom08", "d.results.addressLine1", "d.results.custom07", "d.results.addressLine2", "d.results.sciLastModified", "d.results.custom09", "d.results.onboardingId", "d.results.state", "d.results.fax", "d.results.mi", "d.results.timeZone", "d.results.defaultLocale", "d.results.firstName", "d.results.teamMembersSize", "d.results.lastReviewDate", "d.results.businessPhone", "d.results.lastModified", "d.results.status", "d.results.empId", "d.results.lastName", "d.results.gender", "d.results.impactOfLoss", "d.results.city", "d.results.benchStrength", "d.results.displayName", "d.results.department", "d.results.isPrimaryAssignment", "d.results.email", "d.results.assignmentUUID", "d.results.hireDate", "d.results.companyExitDate", "d.results.talentPool", "d.results.custom11", "d.results.defaultFullName", "d.results.custom10", "d.results.reasonForLeaving", "d.results.riskOfLoss", "d.results.custom13", "d.results.custom12", "d.results.custom15", "d.results.custom14", "d.results.location", "d.results.totalTeamSize", "d.results.username", "d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav", "d.results.secondManager", "d.results.nominationNav", "d.results.reasonForLeavingNav", "d.results.hr", "d.results.incumbentOfPositionNav", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFOBusinessUnitNav", "d.results.customManager", "d.results.costCenterManagerOfFOCostCenterNav", "d.results.employmentIdentityOfDRTMPurgeFreezeNav", "d.results.matrixManager", "d.results.secondReports", "d.results.custom02Nav", "d.results.proxy", "d.results.userIdOfEmployeePayrollRunResultsNav", "d.results.matrixReports", "d.results.directReports", "d.results.externalCodeOfSkillProfileNav", "d.results.personKeyNav", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFODepartmentNav", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFODivisionNav", "d.results.hrReports", "d.results.riskOfLossNav", "d.results.benchStrengthNav", "d.results.manager", "d.results.assigneeUserIdOfDomainEventAlertNav", "d.results.talentPoolNav", "d.results.impactOfLossNav", "d.results.ownerOfTalentPoolNav", "d.results.competencyRatingNav", "d.results.customReports", "d.results.userPermissionsNav", "d.results.delegateeOfAutoDelegateDetailNav"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.__metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results1", "d.results.__metadata", {"uri", "type"}, {"d.results.__metadata.uri", "d.results.__metadata.type"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results.__metadata", "d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav", {"__deferred"}, {"d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav", "d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred", {"uri"}, {"d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred.uri"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.secondManager" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred", "d.results.secondManager", {"__deferred"}, {"d.results.secondManager.__deferred"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.secondManager.__deferred" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results.secondManager", "d.results.secondManager.__deferred", {"uri"}, {"d.results.secondManager.__deferred.uri"}),
    #"Expanded d.results.nominationNav" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded d.results.secondManager.__deferred", "d.results.nominationNav", {"__deferred"}, {"d.results.nominationNav.__deferred"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded d.results.delegateeOfAutoDelegateDetailNav.__deferred",{{"d.results.__metadata.uri", type text}, {"d.results.__metadata.type", type text}, {"d.results.userId", type text}, {"d.results.country", type text}, {"d.results.zipCode", Int64.Type}, {"d.results.lastModifiedDateTime", type text}, {"d.results.reviewFreq", type any}, {"d.results.jobCode", type text}, {"d.results.lastModifiedWithTZ", type text}, {"d.results.division", type text}, {"d.results.custom02", type text}, {"d.results.custom01", type any}, {"d.results.custom04", type text}, {"d.results.custom03", Int64.Type}, {"d.results.custom06", type text}, {"d.results.custom05", type text}, {"d.results.custom08", type any}, {"d.results.addressLine1", type any}, {"d.results.custom07", type text}, {"d.results.addressLine2", type any}, {"d.results.sciLastModified", type text}, {"d.results.custom09", type any}, {"d.results.onboardingId", type any}, {"d.results.state", type text}, {"d.results.fax", type any}, {"d.results.mi", type text}, {"d.results.timeZone", type text}, {"d.results.defaultLocale", type text}, {"d.results.firstName", type text}, {"d.results.teamMembersSize", Int64.Type}, {"d.results.lastReviewDate", type any}, {"d.results.businessPhone", type any}, {"d.results.lastModified", type text}, {"d.results.status", type text}, {"d.results.empId", Int64.Type}, {"d.results.lastName", type text}, {"d.results.gender", type text}, {"d.results.impactOfLoss", type any}, {"d.results.city", type text}, {"d.results.benchStrength", type any}, {"d.results.displayName", type text}, {"d.results.department", type text}, {"d.results.isPrimaryAssignment", type logical}, {"d.results.email", type text}, {"d.results.assignmentUUID", type text}, {"d.results.hireDate", type text}, {"d.results.companyExitDate", type any}, {"d.results.talentPool", type any}, {"d.results.custom11", type any}, {"d.results.defaultFullName", type text}, {"d.results.custom10", type any}, {"d.results.reasonForLeaving", type any}, {"d.results.riskOfLoss", type any}, {"d.results.custom13", type any}, {"d.results.custom12", type any}, {"d.results.custom15", type any}, {"d.results.custom14", type any}, {"d.results.location", type text}, {"d.results.totalTeamSize", Int64.Type}, {"d.results.username", type text}, {"d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.secondManager.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.nominationNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.reasonForLeavingNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.hr.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.incumbentOfPositionNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.headOfUnitOfFOBusinessUnitNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.customManager.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.costCenterManagerOfFOCostCenterNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.employmentIdentityOfDRTMPurgeFreezeNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.matrixManager.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.secondReports.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.custom02Nav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.proxy.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.userIdOfEmployeePayrollRunResultsNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.matrixReports.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.directReports.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.externalCodeOfSkillProfileNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.personKeyNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.headOfUnitOfFODepartmentNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.headOfUnitOfFODivisionNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.hrReports.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.riskOfLossNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.benchStrengthNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.manager.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.assigneeUserIdOfDomainEventAlertNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.talentPoolNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.impactOfLossNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.ownerOfTalentPoolNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.competencyRatingNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.customReports.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.userPermissionsNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.results.delegateeOfAutoDelegateDetailNav.__deferred.uri", type text}, {"d.__next", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"d.results.__metadata.uri", "d.results.lastModifiedDateTime", "d.results.lastModifiedWithTZ", "d.results.lastModified", "d.results.hireDate", "d.results.delegatorOfAutoDelegateConfigNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.secondManager.__deferred.uri", "d.results.nominationNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.reasonForLeavingNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.hr.__deferred.uri", "d.results.incumbentOfPositionNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFOBusinessUnitNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.customManager.__deferred.uri", "d.results.costCenterManagerOfFOCostCenterNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.employmentIdentityOfDRTMPurgeFreezeNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.matrixManager.__deferred.uri", "d.results.secondReports.__deferred.uri", "d.results.custom02Nav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.proxy.__deferred.uri", "d.results.userIdOfEmployeePayrollRunResultsNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.matrixReports.__deferred.uri", "d.results.directReports.__deferred.uri", "d.results.externalCodeOfSkillProfileNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.personKeyNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFODepartmentNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.headOfUnitOfFODivisionNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.hrReports.__deferred.uri", "d.results.riskOfLossNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.benchStrengthNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.manager.__deferred.uri", "d.results.assigneeUserIdOfDomainEventAlertNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.talentPoolNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.impactOfLossNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.ownerOfTalentPoolNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.competencyRatingNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.customReports.__deferred.uri", "d.results.userPermissionsNav.__deferred.uri", "d.results.delegateeOfAutoDelegateDetailNav.__deferred.uri", "d.__next", "d.results.__metadata.type"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"d.results.empId", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each true),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"d.results.empId"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"`

I need to bring all the data from this API, and I want to keep this code but just modify it to add the pagination or something to retrieve this issue.

The api limits you to 1,000 records per call. You can use the contents of the  __next record to obtain the next 1000 records.

Thank you for providing sufficient information to be able to replicate your problem.
There may be better solutions, but this seems to work.
The API limit is 1000 records per call. However, if there are additional records to be had, the return record includes a __next field which contains the url for the next set of records.
I created a custom function which calls a full page of records:
(url as text, headers as record)=>

let 
    return = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, headers)),

//return the URL for the next set, otherwise return false
    nx = try return[d][__next] otherwise false

in

//two (2) element List including results and next url
    {return[d][results], nx}

and then, in the main query:
let
    Headers = [Headers=[Authorization="Basic QkMwMDBJTlRAYWJkdWxsYWhhYjpTY2llbmNlU29mdDE5ODk="]],
    url = "https://api55.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/User?$format=JSON",

//Make repeated api calls so long as 
// results are being returned
    #"All Pages" = List.Generate(
        ()=>[p=fnOnePage(url,Headers)],
        each (try [p]{0})[HasError]=false,
        each [p = fnOnePage([p]{1}, Headers)] ,
        each [p]{0}),

//Convert List to table and expand the column of records
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"All Pages", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1")
in
    #"Expanded Column"

The above returns a table of 3,644 rows where each row consists of a Record.

You can then expand and filter those records to create your report.
